# Customizing WinForms ErrorProvider to display its icon inside control's entry

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, custom-controls, errorprovider

I have some custom/user controls that in most cases have label and entry, like this:

*removed dead ImageShack link*

Is there any way I can customize the standard WinForms ErrorProvider to display its icon inside entry (entry - textbox, combo, datetime etc...), like this:

*removed dead ImageShack link*

where the red circle is of course the error indicator.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I've found a solution:

```
this.errorProvider.SetIconPadding(this.textBox, -20);
```

where errorProvider is an ErrorProvider Object and textBox is an Entry object.

Comment: not sure how good this is, but for me a possible solution to the magic number is: `errorProvider.Icon.Width + textBox.Bounds.Width - textBox.ClientRectangle.Width`. Of course the icon size *should* be appropriate to the `textBox.Height` but that's often the case (16x16 icon, textBox default height is 20)